# How do I get out of this sewer pit in Thieves’ Guild?

Tags: thief-the-dark-project, thief-gold

I found this pit:

[image: Screenshot 1]

So I jumped into it and found that large door/valve will not open. Now I cannot find a way out or back up:

[image: Screenshot 2]

How do I get out? The dark corner has nothing either.

[image: Screenshot 3]

I cannot use a Rope arrow, there's nothing to attach it to.

Comment: Are you sure there is no ladder in it? Sometimes ladders could be very difficult to see in Thief. In your second pic, there is a platform where the two lower torches are. It looks wooden or is it?

Comment: There's no ladders, I've checked so many times. :(

Comment: What about the wooden looking part? Are you able to shoot your rope arrow at it?

Comment: Which wood part? Rope arrows only go straight down, I think.

Comment: The one I mentioned in my first comment?

Answer (score -1):

Shoot a rope arrow into the edge of the platform you came from